# zoomIn effect (Animate.css) doesnt works in second click or without page load

Tags: jquery, css, animate.css

I am trying to zoomIn a text using animate.css on every click of a button.It works only for first time. If page load it works again for first time. Need a help.

html:

```
<div class="row contact-section">
   <div class="col-md-12">
       <h1 id='an'> contact section</h1>
   </div>
</div>

<button class='.mini-contact'>animate</button>
```

jquery:

```
$('.mini-contact').on('click',function(){
 $('.contact-section').fadeIn();
 $('#an').addClass('animated zoomIn');
})
```

Comment: You're probably going to need JS.

Comment: Any examples of what you have tried?

Comment: why not use `$(document).ready` rather than page load?

Comment: i have edited the post and add a code sample

Answer (score 0):

it would be because you are not reapplying the classes ( replaying the animation )

Try this:

```js
function appyAnim(x) {
    $('#animationSandbox').removeClass().addClass(x + ' animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
      $(this).removeClass();
    });
  };

  $(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.js--triggerAnimation').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var anim = "zoomIn";
      applyAnim(anim);
    });

    
  });
```

```html
<!--this be your button -->
<button class="butt js--triggerAnimation">Animate</button>

<!-- this be what you are animating -->
<span id="animationSandbox" style="display: block;" class=""><h1 class="site__title mega">TEXT HERE</h1></span>
```

Comment: thanks. i tried .. but no luck !! ..

Comment: its working .... check the console, is it showing some error??

Comment: thanks Bro !! it works with slide different approach. Ur suggestion helped me. thanks. here is the link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566532/animate-css-doesnt-work-for-second-click/26572345#26572345

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle I created for you: http://jsfiddle.net/4ggaof1u/

Correction in button class, remove dot(.), it should be `class='mini-contact'`
And your script would be like below

```
$(function () {
    $('.mini-contact').on('click', function () {
        var $el = $('#an'),
            c = 'zoomIn animated';
        $('.contact-section').fadeIn(1, function () {
            $el.addClass(c);
        }).delay(1000).show(0, function () {
            $el.removeClass(c)
        });
    });

});
```