# Animate.css doesnt work for Second click

Tags: jquery, animate.css

If i click .img-1 or .img-2 first time it works. bt not in second time without page refresh. I am using Animate.css (zoomIn). Here is the code sample --

html:

```
<a class="thumbnail img-1"></a>
<a class="thumbnail img-2"></a>

<p class='back-end'>
<p class='front-end'></p>
<h1 class='dismiss pull-right'>&times;</h1>
```

jquery:

```
$('.img-1,.img-2').click(function(){
    $('.back-end,.front-end,.dismiss').addClass('animated zoomIn').show();
})

$('.dismiss').click(function(){
    $('.back-end,.front-end,.dismiss').addClass('animated zoomOut');
})
```

Comment: It should be related to animation conflicts, try removing the `zoomIn` and `zoomOut` classes before adding other animation related classes.

Answer (score 2):

See it in jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/oxu69Luw/

Script would be like below:

```
$(function () {
    function applyZoomInOutAnim(x) {
        $('.back-end,.front-end,.dismiss').removeClass("zoomIn zoomOut").addClass(x + ' animated');
    }

    $('.img-1,.img-2').click(function () {
        applyZoomInOutAnim('zoomIn');
    });

    $('.dismiss').click(function () {
        applyZoomInOutAnim('zoomOut');
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks bro. Your code piece seems fine. but i tried it. still no luck. what should i do ?? :(

Comment: also it is now not animating even in first time

Comment: thanks  Venkata Panga for ur help.. i have successfully done! with some modification. thanks bro. i paste my code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but I think you have to .removeClass first ... and then when you want to play the animation again you have to .addClass again

Comment: i tried this way --

[code]
$('.thumbnail').each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
    $('.back-end,.front-end,.dismiss').addClass('animated zoomIn').show();
  })
  $('.back-end,.front-end,.dismiss').removeClass('animated zoomIn');
})
[/code]

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/wahidsherief/e87dkpbf/1/

Markup :

```
<p class='back-end'>
    <p class='front-end'></p>
     <h1 class='dismiss pull-right'>&times;</h1>
</p>

<a class="thumbnail img-1"> image 1</a>
<a class="thumbnail img-2"> image 2</a>
```

css :

```
.back-end{position: absolute; width: 100%;height: 100%;background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);    z-index: 600}
.front-end {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;height: 65%;left: 16%;position: absolute;top: 22%;width: 68%;z-index: 1000;}
.dismiss{color: black;z-index: 2000;background:red;padding: 30px 50px;font-size: 60px;cursor: pointer;}
```

Script :

```
$('.back-end,.front-end,.dismiss').hide();

function applyZoomInOutAnim(x) {
    $('.back-end,.front-end,.dismiss').removeClass("zoomIn zoomOut").addClass(x +' animated');
}

$('.thumbnail').click(function () {
    applyZoomInOutAnim('zoomIn');
     $('.back-end,.front-end,.dismiss').show();
});

$('.dismiss').click(function () {
    applyZoomInOutAnim('zoomOut');
     $('.back-end,.front-end,.dismiss').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
            $(this).hide();
     });

});
```